# Lightest way to add vector drawable support

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

So I faced an error on pre 21 Android API devices while inflate ImageButton with vector drawable.
I added this because I want my app be as light as possible.

> implementation group: 'com.android.support', name:
>   'support-vector-drawable', version: '28.0.0'

Also I changed `android:src` to `app:srcCompat` and added `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`, but when I compile my apk, I get an error.

> error: attribute srcCompat (aka {package}:srcCompat) not found.

What lib I should use to provide vectors support?

Comment: What is your app namespace? Try to post your layput codes

Comment: It is not layout or namespace issue